# How to get Airflow's previous execution date regardless of how the DAG is triggered?

Tags: airflow

When I trigger a DAG manually, prev_execution_date and execution_date are the same.

```
echo_exec_date = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_script',
    bash_command='echo "prev_exec_date={{ prev_execution_date }} execution_date={{ execution_date }}"',
    dag=dag)
```

results in:

```
prev_exec_date=2022-06-29T08:50:37.506898+00:00 execution_date=2022-06-29T08:50:37.506898+00:00
```

They are different if the DAG is triggered automatically by the scheduler.

I would like to have `prev_execution_date` regardless of triggering it manually or automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When manually triggering DAG, the schedule will be ignored, and `prev_execution_date == next_execution_date == execution_date`
This is explained in the Airflow [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#why-next-ds-or-prev-ds-might-not-contain-expected-values)

This is because previous / next of manual run is not something that is well defined. Consider you have a daily schedule (say at 00:00) and you invoke a manual run on 13:00. What is the expected next schedule? should it be daily from 00:00 or daily from 13:00? a DagRun can have only 1 prev and only 1 next. In your senario it seems like you are interested in a case where there can be more than 1 or that the manual run "comes between" the two scheduled runs. This is not something that Airflow supports - It really over complicate things.

If you want to workaround it you can create custom macro that checks the `run_type`, searches the specific DagRun that you consider as previous and return it's `execution_date`. Be noted that it might create some side effects (overlapping data interval process etc..) you need to really verify that the logic you implement make sense for your specific use case.